Android Studio Emulator Terminates exit code 1, unknown option: -qt-hide-window
I have a new install of Android Studio, Koala Drop, running on Windows 10.  I can't seem to get a virtual device running.  I think the issue is in the logs, which seem to indicate that the emulator doesn't understand its command line arguments:
2024-10-17 09:15:20,096 [ 923930]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API 35 - unknown option: -qt-hide-window
2024-10-17 09:15:20,096 [ 923930]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API 35 - please use -help for a list of valid options
2024-10-17 09:15:20,234 [ 924068]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API 35 - Process finished with exit code 1

Anyone have any ideas what's up with this?  I could supply other logs or configuration info if needed.  I've already re-installed the whole IDE once to see if that helped, it didn't. Here's some more logs around those lines above if it helps.
2024-10-17 09:15:19,683 [ 923517]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr

2024-10-17 09:15:19,687 [ 923521]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Build command line options: [--continue, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, -Pandroid.studio.version=241.19072.14.2412.12360217, -Pandroid.injected.attribution.file.location=C:\Users\Brenden\Google Drive\proj\AndroidStudio\LeadningIDE2\.gradle]

2024-10-17 09:15:19,699 [ 923533]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.s.e.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line to Gradle Tooling API: -Pandroid.injected.enableStableIds=true -Pandroid.injected.build.api=35 -Pandroid.injected.build.abi=x86_64 --stacktrace --continue -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.studio.version=241.19072.14.2412.12360217 -Pandroid.injected.attribution.file.location=C:\Users\Brenden\Google Drive\proj\AndroidStudio\LeadningIDE2\.gradle -Didea.active=true -Didea.version=2024.1 -Didea.vendor.name=Google

2024-10-17 09:15:19,833 [ 923667]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API 35 - C:\Users\Brenden\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_5_API_35 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300

2024-10-17 09:15:20,096 [ 923930]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API 35 - unknown option: -qt-hide-window

2024-10-17 09:15:20,096 [ 923930]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API 35 - please use -help for a list of valid options

2024-10-17 09:15:20,234 [ 924068]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API 35 - Process finished with exit code 1

2024-10-17 09:15:20,234 [ 924068]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 5 API 35 - Emulator terminated with exit code 1

2024-10-17 09:15:21,634 [ 925468]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr

2024-10-17 09:15:21,640 [ 925474]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr

2024-10-17 09:15:21,792 [ 925626]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTask - Couldn't get post build models.

2024-10-17 09:15:21,792 [ 925626]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTask - Gradle invocation complete, build result = com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.AssembleInvocationResult@167a4c0b

2024-10-17 09:15:21,792 [ 925626]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Gradle build finished in 2 s 113 ms

2024-10-17 09:15:21,820 [ 925654]   INFO - #c.i.e.r.ExecutionUtil - Error running 'app':<br>The emulator process for AVD Pixel_5_API_35 has terminated.

com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_5_API_35 has terminated.

    at com.android.tools.idea.execution.common.AndroidConfigurationProgramRunner$execute$5.run(AndroidConfigurationProgramRunner.kt:135)

    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.startTask(CoreProgressManager.java:477)

    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.startTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:133)

    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsynchronously$6(CoreProgressManager.java:528)

    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:250)

    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$0(ProgressManager.java:100)

    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:221)

    at com.intellij.platform.diagnostic.telemetry.helpers.TraceKt.use(trace.kt:46)

    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:220)

    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$13(CoreProgressManager.java:660)

    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:735)

    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:691)

    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:659)

    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:79)

    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:202)

    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.runProcess(ProgressManager.java:100)

    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$5(ProgressRunner.java:250)

    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner$ProgressRunnable.run(ProgressRunner.java:500)

    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ChildContext$runAsCoroutine$1.invoke(propagation.kt:81)

    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ChildContext$runAsCoroutine$1.invoke(propagation.kt:81)

    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ChildContext.runAsCoroutine(propagation.kt:86)

    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ChildContext.runAsCoroutine(propagation.kt:81)

    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$launchTask$18(ProgressRunner.java:466)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)

    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)

    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

Caused by: com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$EmulatorTerminatedException: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_5_API_35 has terminated.

    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$WaitForEmulatorTask.run(EmulatorConnectionListener.java:93)

    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.RwLockHolder$executeOnPooledThread$1.run(RwLockHolder.kt:154)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

    ... 7 more



You can try editing the emulator files.

Open .android\avd\Pixel_5_API_35.avd
try removing qt-hide-window


better to use list of items when suggesting a series of steps, it helps in easier understanding for the reader
